# Hide private ip addresses from VPN user in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vpn, azure-vpn, virtual-network

I have the following issue. I have a Azure virtual network with loadbalancer and 2 VM's. They all have internal IP's obiously (e.g. 10.0.0.1). I have an Azure Point 2 Site VPN setup to connect to my virtual network. Now a third party wants to connect to the SQL instance on the VM via Azure P2S VPN, but giving them access using the same VPN as me, they also get all the internal ip's (of the other VM's). This blocks their own usage for those IP's, since they might already have their own use for 10.0.0.1 in their network.

They want to use a specific IP address, and only connect to that, and not implicitly conflict with my azure virt. network IP's that they might be using themselves. How can I provide access via VPN without including my own internal IP's?

I thought about creating a second virtual network + second VPN, and use vnet-to-vnet, but I'm not sure if this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought about creating a second virtual network + second VPN, and
>   use vnet-to-vnet, but I'm not sure if this will work.

No, Azure does **not** support this.

> They want to use a specific IP address, and only connect to that, and
>   not implicitly conflict with my azure virt. network IP's that they
>   might be using themselves.

In Azure, we deploy a VPN, we should make sure the address spaces you specify **don't overlap** any of the address spaces that you have on your on-premises network.

> How can I provide access via VPN without including my own internal
>   IP's?

In your scenario, I think we can create a windows VM and deploy it as a **RRAS** server, so we can connect Azure via RRAS VPN, in this way, we can define the  “Static address pool” for the number of clients, the address spaces you specify will not overlap any of the address spaces that you have on your on-premises network.  (just work for **windows**)

If you want to use **Linux** to connect azure, I think we can try to use some software VPN.

Comment: Thanks, for the second point, will the azure vpn client installer overwrite existing addresses on premise?

Comment: @user2713516 Based on my knowledge, Azure VPN client installer will **not overwrite** existing addresses on premise.